# Error Json Validation against JsonSchema and anyOf

Tags: json, validation, jsonschema

I have a json to validate against jsonSchema,
I don't understand why i have an error with the first anyOf, indeed, we can have either a null value, either an array... i set an array but error tells found array instaed of null value?

of course the second error is made intentionnally to see if validator works, but error not null required cause 2 more messages i don't understand

Why ?

the json to validate

```
{"simpleTests":[{"attr1":null,"attr2":null,"chiffre":12},{"attr1":"attr1","attr2":"test2"}]}
```

and the schema

```
    {
   "$schema":"http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
   "title":"Simple Test Wrapper",
   "type":"object",
   "additionalProperties":false,
   "properties":{
      "simpleTests":{
         "oneOf":[
            {
               "type":"null",
               "title":"Not included"
            },
            {
               "type":"array",
               "items":{
                  "$ref":"#/definitions/SimpleTest"
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      "attribute1":{
         "oneOf":[
            {
               "type":"null",
               "title":"Not included"
            },
            {
               "type":"string"
            }
         ]
      },
      "number2":{
         "oneOf":[
            {
               "type":"null",
               "title":"Not included"
            },
            {
               "type":"integer"
            }
         ]
      }
   },
   "definitions":{
      "SimpleTest":{
         "type":"object",
         "additionalProperties":false,
         "properties":{
            "attr1":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "attr2":{
               "oneOf":[
                  {
                     "type":"null",
                     "title":"Not included"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"string"
                  }
               ]
            },
            "chiffre":{
               "oneOf":[
                  {
                     "type":"null",
                     "title":"Not included"
                  },
                  {
                     "type":"integer"
                  }
               ]
            }
         },
         "required":[
            "attr1"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

and the errors

```
Message:
JSON is valid against no schemas from 'oneOf'.
Schema path:
#/properties/simpleTests/oneOf
Message:
Invalid type. Expected Null but got Array.
Schema path:
#/properties/simpleTests/oneOf/0/type
Message:
Invalid type. Expected String but got Null.
Schema path:
#/definitions/SimpleTest/properties/attr1/type
```

i don't understand the 2 firsts errors because it is normal...  (all code is generated by java code, and validated by java code) here i use

https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

to test validation

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not fit and is not clear

Answer (score 2):

The results you received only contain the schema location.  You might get some better understanding from [json-everything.net](https://json-everything.net/json-schema) which will give a bit more comprehensive results, including the instance location.

The primary issue, is at `#/simpleTests/0/attr1`, which is null, but the subschema at `#/properties/simpleTests/oneOf/1/items/$ref/properties/attr1/type` only allows strings.

Changing your instance to

```json
{
  "simpleTests":[
    {
      "attr1":"string",   // this is changed
      "attr2":null,
      "chiffre":12
    },
    {
      "attr1":"attr1",
      "attr2":"test2"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

As a side note, you can use an array form in `type` to list multiple types:

```json
"oneOf":[
  {
    "type":"null",
    "title":"Not included"
  },
  {
    "type":"array",
    "items":{
      "$ref":"#/definitions/SimpleTest"
    }
  }
]
```

can be rewritten as

```json
{
  "type": [ "null", "array" ],
  "items": {
    "$ref":"#/definitions/SimpleTest"
  }
}
```

Comment: i think it depends on what draft you use.... internally type array is making oneOf

Comment: The validator I linked is mine. I've implemented draft 4.  `type` is the same as in later drafts.

Comment: (to be clear, I implemented draft 4 in the predecessor to the library that powers the validator above)

Answer (score 0):

you have to fix attribute1 property validation, should add one more, that allows null

```
 "properties": {
        "attr1": {
          "oneOf": [
            {
              "type": "null",
              "title": "Not included"
            },
            {
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        },
```

Comment: hello, i made the error the question was about 2 first messages but it is normal